# How to say "death-sick?"

Tags: single-word-requests, american-english, synonyms

I am searching for a replacement for “death-sick” (or is it “dead-sick”) from the sentence:

> “A stigmatized physician falls into an organ donor scheme through which for every human organ he delivers his death-sick daughter gets an extra month of life.”

His daughter suffers from a rare brain disease, for which there is no treatment. I found “brainsick,” which means nuts. “Nauseous, invalid, sickish, anemic” are all too soft for this case.

Comment: You might be looking for "fatally ill" or "terminally ill".

Comment: lol, I only had to read as far as 'physician falls' to know who this question was from!

Comment: @diracdeltafunk I didn't spot your comment when I wrote my answer. I'll happily delete if you want to post an answer.

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Deathly+ill%2Cdeathly+sick%2Cterminally+ill%2Cdeathly+sick&case_insensitive=on&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2CDeathly%20ill%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bdeathly%20ill%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BDeathly%20ill%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cdeathly%20sick%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bdeathly%20sick%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BDeathly%20sick%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cterminally%20ill%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bterminally%20ill%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BTerminally%20ill%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cdeathly%20sick%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bdeathly%20sick%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BDeathly%20sick%3B%2Cc0 shows  terminally ill is the usual option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest '[terminally il](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_illness)l' or 'terminally sick'

> Terminal illness is a disease that cannot be cured or adequately treated and that is reasonably expected to result in the death of the patient within a short period of time. This term is more commonly used for progressive diseases such as cancer or advanced heart disease than for trauma. In popular use, it indicates a disease that will soon progress until death with near absolute certainty, regardless of treatment.

[Terminal](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/terminally)

> 8. occurring at or causing the end of life:
>      a terminal disease.

Other appropriate synonym adverbs include *fatally* or *mortally*.

Answer (score 3):

The phrase I would use is ***deathly ill***, as in these articles:

> [AP FACT CHECK: Willie Nelson not deathly ill, publicist says](https://apnews.com/10fc6fa8dae744c6badf098e6876ae82/ap-fact-check-willie-nelson-not-deathly-ill-publicist-says)
>
> [This day in history: Keats falls deathly ill](http://www.history.com/this-day-in-history/keats-falls-deathly-ill)
>
> [How jelly beans made a Canadian man deathly ill, and highlighted the dangers of licorice](http://nationalpost.com/g00/health/how-jelly-beans-made-a-canadian-man-deathly-ill-and-highlighted-the-dangers-of-licorice/wcm/418d7a6b-d1ac-480d-8e0f-bffbae1e573e?i10c.referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F)

So, for your sentence, it would be:

> A stigmatized physician falls into an organ donor scheme through which for every human organ he delivers his ***deathly ill*** daughter gets an extra month of life.